# Sorting mysql results on the basis of relevance to query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm searching mysql database using user's query with php via html form.

```
SELECT * FROM Collection WHERE `Name` LIKE '%$query%';
```

I want to sort the results with the row having highest matching score on the top in decreasing order with matching score.
How to do this?

Comment: how do you if it's the highest matching score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must take a look at `FULLTEXT` search in `Boolean` mode.

#### [Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Collection WHERE `Name` LIKE '%$query%' ORDER By name ASC;
```

use the above query for sorting